# Nested JOIN to create custom dynamic columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table **veicoli** (vehicles) like this:

```
-------------------------------
| ID  |   Modello |   Targa   | 
-------------------------------
| 1   |   IVECO   |   XA123WE |     
-------------------------------
| 2   |   IVECO   |   CF556XD |   
-------------------------------
| 3   |   FIAT    |   AS332ZZ | 
-------------------------------
| 4   |   GOLF    |   GF567YU | 
-------------------------------
```

For each vehicle I have none, one or multiple **revisioni_veicolo** (revisions) (the one with bigger `DateExpiring` is the one I need to check if revision is still valid or not based on today date)

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |   veicoli_ID   |   DateExpiring         |     Pass_Success |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |   1            | 2019-07-01             |        1
------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   |   1            | 2020-10-01             |        0
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3   |   2            | 2019-11-25             |        1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4   |   2            | 2018-10-20             |        1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5   |   4            | 2017-10-20             |        1
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Based on my example above (**today is 2019-10-29**):

Vehicle: ID = 1 has a revision still active (2020-10-01) but not passed (Pass_success = 0)

Vehicle: ID = 2 has a revision still active (2019-11-25) and passed (Pass_success = 1)

Vehicle: ID = 3 has no revision yet

Vehicle: ID = 4 has revision, but no active revision (last expired on 2017-10-20) but the last one passed the check (Pass_success = 1)

What I need is to have 3 new custom columns created dynamically on my query result:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ID  |   Modello |   Targa   |  RevisionPresent | RevisionStillActive | LastRevisionPassed |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   |   IVECO   |   XA123WE |      true        |   true              |   false  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   |   IVECO   |   CF556XD |      true        |   true              |   true
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3   |   FIAT    |   AS332ZZ |       false      |   false             |  false
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4   |   GOLF    |   GF567YU |       true       |   false             |  true
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried to start with my old post: [MYSQL INNER JOIN to get 3 types of result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58603726/mysql-inner-join-to-get-3-types-of-result/58603933?noredirect=1#comment103522368_58603933)

But I'm very confused using nested JOIN

I tried starting a fiddle but i'm stuck on syntax error: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c70bf/2

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8.0? Window functions would make this easier.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.6.17 on localhost using WAMP SERVER for test. Also i'm using SQLyog software to get some basic queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a LEFT JOIN of the tables and conditional aggregation:

```
select v.ID, v.Modello, v.Targa,
  max(r.DataScadenzaRevisione is not null) RevisionPresent,
  coalesce(max(r.DataScadenzaRevisione >= current_date()), 0) RevisionStillActive,
  max(case when r.DataScadenzaRevisione = g.maxdate then r.EsitoPositivo else 0 end) LastRevisionPassed 
from veicoli v 
left join revisioni_veicolo r on r.veicoli_ID = v.id
left join (
  select veicoli_id, max(DataScadenzaRevisione) maxdate 
  from revisioni_veicolo
  group by veicoli_id
) g on g.veicoli_ID = v.id           
group by v.ID, v.Modello, v.Targa
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cxHY8piJUE3C4KMgw6FAr3/2).
Results:

```
| ID  | Modello | Targa   | RevisionPresent | RevisionStillActive | LastRevisionPassed |
| --- | ------- | ------- | --------------- | ------------------- | ------------------ |
| 1   | IVECO   | XA123WE | 1               | 1                   | 0                  |
| 2   | IVECO   | CF556XD | 1               | 1                   | 1                  |
| 3   | FIAT    | AS332ZZ | 0               | 0                   | 0                  |
| 4   | GOLF    | GF567YU | 1               | 0                   | 1                  |
```

Comment: Hi thank you very much. Only one field is incorrect: For vehicle 4 -> LastRevisionPassed must be true

Comment: Can you explain once more the logic? For all 4 vehicles why the results should be 0, 1, 0, 1?

Comment: Hi, why vehicles ID = 4 has no revision actives...but the last one for vehicle 4 (expired on 2017-10-20) was passed = true. LastRevisionPassed is based on latest revision for each vehicles (it doesn't matter if expired or not)

Answer (score 0):

```
...
LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.veicoli_ID, a.EsitoPositivo AS StatoUltimaRevisione,
  a.DataScadenzaRevisione FROM revisioni_veicolo) a
...
```

There's two things wrong with this.

- The alias `a` is defined for this subquery, so you can't reference it inside the subquery. But you don't need to qualify the columns in this subquery anyway - you didn't do this in other subqueries, so I'm not sure why you did it in this case.
- You don't have any join condition for this join. MySQL is a little bit inconsistent about when join conditions are required. But in this case, you need one.

After I tested the query with these two corrections, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you just need to look at the last revision of each vehicule to produce that resultset.

You can do the filtering with a correlated subquery:

```
select
    v.ID,
    v.Modello,
    v.Targa,
    (DataScadenzaRevisione >= now()) RevisionPresent,
    (DataScadenzaRevisione >= now() and EsitoPositivo = 1) RevisionStillActive,
    (EsitoPositivo = 1) LastRevisionPassed 
from 
    veicoli v
    left join revisioni_veicolo r 
        on r.veicoli_ID = v.ID
        and r.DataScadenzaRevisione = (
            select max(DataScadenzaRevisione) 
            from revisioni_veicolo r1 
            where r1.veicoli_ID = v.ID
    )
```

You can check the results with your sample data in [this db fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c70bf/8).

Or you can use a window function (this requires MySQL 8.0):

```
select
    v.ID,
    v.Modello,
    v.Targa,
    (DataScadenzaRevisione >= now()) RevisionPresent,
    (DataScadenzaRevisione >= now() and EsitoPositivo = 1) RevisionStillActive,
    (EsitoPositivo = 1) LastRevisionPassed 
from (
    select 
        v.*, 
        r.*, 
        row_number() over(partition by ID order by r.DataScadenzaRevisione desc) rn
    from veicoli v
    left join revisioni_veicolo r on r.veicoli_ID = v.ID
) where coaelesce(rn, 1) = 1
```

Comment: Hi thankyou for your simplified code! It seems there a 2 errors: Vehicle with ID = 1 has wrong RevisionStillActive. Vehicle with ID = 4 has wrong RevisionPresent